Unable to Link CSS Files in EJS Template
In my ejs file (result1.ejs), I can't link with css file or any other image and everything.
Here is the folder structure (I removed some of the files that is not necessary to the question)
project/
├── node_modules
├── public/
│   └── assets/
│       ├── favicon.png
│       ├── GraphikRegular.otf
│       ├── root.css
│       └── result.css
├── views/
│   ├── card.ejs
│   └── result.ejs
├── .env
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── server.js

Here is the server.js (I removed some of the uncessary codes that aren't related to the question)
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { render } = require("ejs");

// other importing code

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("src"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.post("/scrape", async (req, res) => {
  const reveiwLink = req.body.review_link;

  try {
    // puppeteer extracting the data code
    const renderedHTML = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      res.render(
        "card",
        {
          data: {
        data1,
        data2
          },
        },
        (err, html) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(html);
          }
        }
      );
    });

    res.render("result", {
      data: {
        renderedHTML,
      },
    });
    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "An error occurred while fetching the review" });
  }
});

app.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
  const renderedHTML = req.body.renderedHTML; 
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote",
      ],
      executablePath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? process.env.PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH
          : puppeteer.executablePath(),
      headless: true,
      defaultViewport: null,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(renderedHTML);

    // Capture the screenshot of the desired element
    const element = await page.$("#htmlContent");
    const screenshotBuffer = await element.screenshot();

    await browser.close();

    // Set the appropriate headers for image download
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=card.png");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");

    // Send the screenshot buffer as a response
    res.send(screenshotBuffer);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "An error occurred while generating the screenshot" });
  }
});

In the result.ejs
        <form action="/download" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="renderedHTML" value="<%= locals.data.renderedHTML %>">
            <button type="submit">Download</button>
        </form>

In the card.ejs
I tried to link the card.css and root.css files by writing like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/root.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/card.css">

but the styles don't work.
I can link to root.css in the result.ejs by writing like this though.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/root.css">
It's not just css files not cannot be linked in the card.ejs, I have tried with images too,
I put an image (abc.jpg) in every folder and also in the root-folder
not then in the card.ejs, I have tried to link the image by writing like this
<img src="abc.jpg">
and still the image doesn't show up.
What I wanted to do was basically like a Twitter screenshot generator, instead of Twitter, I wanted to generate screenshot card of the Letterboxd review. So, when the user give the Letterboxd user review, I'll scrape the data and recreate the review card on my own and then take the screenshot of the review card element I created and then send it back to the user.
Here is the Github repo

app.post("/scrape" is confusing. res.render should only be called once and it looks like there's an unnecessary new Promise. What is this app supposed to accomplish exactly? You're passing some HTML back to app.post("/download" to turn it into a PDF, and that HTML doesn't have CSS? That seems like the expected behavior--why would this string of HTML know where the CSS is without a link or inline style? I suggest taking a step back and explaining the specification for what your app is supposed to be doing so you can re-approach with a clearer solution.

When you say "the image doesn't show up", are you referring to the PDF or the user's browser UI?

I created renderedHTML and sent it to the result.ejs so that I can use it in the app.post("/download". I'll explain what I intended to do:

in the index page, take the url from the user
go to app.post("/scrape" route
scrape the data and create a html with the scraped data, which is stylised with css
and then in the app.post("/scrape" route after getting the stylised html with scraped data, send the stylised html to the result.ejs
in the result.ejs, there is gonna be download btn, it'll lead to app.post("/download" route
to be continued...


... from the previous comment
6. in there, i want to take the screenshot of the html element by the name #htmlContent where the html is the stylised HTML send from app.post("/scrape"
7. after i get the screenshot buffer, i want to send it to the user.
Basically, I wanted to generate an image out of an url.
Thank you for helping me out with this.

@ggorlen English is not my first language so my explanation might not be clear. If you are still down to help me out, I can share the github repo of the project, so that you can run it on your device and see what I was trying to do. What I wanted to do was basically like a Twitter screenshot generator, instead of Twitter, I wanted to generate screenshot card of the Letterboxd review. So, when the user give the Letterboxd user review, I'll scrape the data and recreate the review card on my own and then take the screenshot of the review card element I created and then send it back to the user.

Thanks, this is all really helpful. I appreciate the time you took here. Can you [edit] the question to include this info and context? I'll try to help if I can. A GH repo is fine to supplement your in-question code. So you're trying to add your own style onto the arbitrary URL's HTML? The separate route/button to download the result makes sense, but the easiest approach here seems like the first route should take the screenshot right away rather than capturing the HTML and trying to screenshot it later on with added CSS. The intermediate HTML/CSS step is the confusing part for me.

I tried to take the screenshot in the first route and then in the sec route, I sent the screenshot to the user. It worked. But I tried to deploy this project on render.com for free, and when I do that. I get the error, saying it can't return the image to the user, something about with permission. That's why, I tried to render the HTML in the first route and take the screenshot in the second route. Actually, even if I could do that, render.com took a lot of time processing, since I was using free plan. I guess I have to stick with the rendering and taking screenshot on the first route method.
